# how to list subdirectory without show parent directory in php

Tags: php, html

I met the problem that I want only show the sub directories but my code I got from google, it show both parent directory and sub directories. my code here:

```
    foreach(glob('Comments/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir){
       echo "<a href=comment.php?dir=". $dir . " >". $dir ."</a><br/>";
    }
```

'Comments' is the parent directory. and each sub directories, I added them to each label link. And the result for this code are:

```
    Comments/New Folder1
    Comments/New Folder2
    Comments/New Folder3
          .
          .
          .
```

And I want to show like this:

```
    New Folder1
    New Folder2
    New Folder3
          .
          .
          .
```

Please everyone help me... Thanks in advance

Comment: Not an actual answer, but a comment. Could you try replacing your `echo...` line with this? `$dir = str_replace(" Comments/", "", $dir); echo "<a href=comment.php?dir=". $dir . " >". $dir ."</a><br/>";`

Comment: @Davinder This makes it dependent from the parents foldername and at least I don't know, if it is really fix. But you can combine `strrpos()` with `substr()` to get a similar result

Comment: @kingcrunch yeah, I assumed that `Comments/` would always be there. Your approach is also one. Another, which is not folder-name dependet is to use explode at `\\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$foldername = basename($dir);
```

[`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) (works for folders too)